# Merge (or spread) two rows in a tibble or data.frame into one row

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyverse

How do I acomplish to reshape from this:

```
df_2row <- data.frame(ID = c("123", "123"), CURR = c("EUR", "USD"), 
                      OtherCOls = c("abc", "abc"), 
                      valueType1_EUR = c(100, NA), valueType2_CURR = c(NA, 110))
```

[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: I want to make my data "presentable" - it's a reporting thing 
The full data.frame has more value (EUR) columns (i.e. 4) and two CURR columns - I tried to strip the problem down a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following could work:

```
library(dplyr)

# create a separate subset data frame for each desired valueType/CURR combination
df.1 <- df_2row %>% select(ID, OtherCOls, valueType1_EUR, CURR) %>% na.omit()
df.2 <- df_2row %>% select(ID, OtherCOls, valueType2_CURR, CURR) %>% na.omit()

# join subsets together by ID & OtherCOls
df.combined <- left_join(df.1, df.2, by = c("ID", "OtherCOls"))

> df.combined
   ID OtherCOls valueType1_EUR CURR.x valueType2_CURR CURR.y
1 123       abc            100    EUR             110    USD
```

If you really need the CURR columns to take on the same name, you can rename the them, though I think that may be confusing.

Comment: Thanks - I could not grasp my head around the na.omit() in the pipe. 
So I solved it with left_joins in a Loop ...and yes I did the renaming after the joinint. 
But I was on the lookout for a piped solution, which you gave me.  
Thanks ... 
Only Thing a bit tedios is that I have up to 15 different CURRs ... but I guess I will manage to lapply the whole structure somehow